# how to scrape metrics with bearer token auth?

Tags: kubernetes, http-headers, authorization, google-kubernetes-engine, victoriametrics

vmagent version: 1.79

i use k8s in GCP

So i create kind - secret, which have a key "bearer" with some secret-key "XXX"

In another kind i want to use this secret-key as base auth token to scrape metrics from host1, host2

i receive an error 404, but if i use curl with header - all ok

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: web-site-token
data:
  bearer: XXX
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: operator.victoriametrics.com/v1beta1
kind: VMStaticScrape
metadata:
  name: web-site
  labels:
    xxx.com/vmagent: nodes
spec:
  jobName: web-site
  targetEndpoints:
    - targets:
        - host1:9254
        - host2:9254
      path: /internal/metrics
      labels:
        env: preupdate
        region: us
        domain: web
        site: game
      scheme: http
      authorization:
        credentials:
          key: bearer
          name: web-site-token
      tlsConfig:
        insecureSkipVerify: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

First kind - secret, where i can store token

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: web-site-token
data:
  bearer: xxx
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: operator.victoriametrics.com/v1beta1
kind: VMStaticScrape
metadata:
  name: web-site
  labels:
    xxx.com/vmagent: nodes
spec:
  jobName: site
  targetEndpoints:
    - targets:
        - xxx.com:9254
      path: /internal/metrics
      labels:
        env: preprod
        region: eu
        domain: web
        site: xxx
      scheme: http
      authorization:
        credentials:
          key: bearer
          name: web-site-token
        type: ' '
```